# Kivy compiling errors on macos

Tags: python, ios, xcode, macos, kivy

trying to compile for iOS my very first python kivy project on macos.

http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

```
$ git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
$ cd kivy-ios
$ tools/build-all.sh
```

If I try to build, terminal works a while and at the end I get this error:

```
....
['/Users/xxx/kivy-ios/tools/liblink', '-arch', 'armv7', '-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk', '-miphoneos-version-min=7.1', '-arch', 'armv7', '-pipe', '-no-cpp-precomp', '-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk', '-miphoneos-version-min=7.1', '-O3', '-Qunused-arguments', 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-armv7-2.7/ios.o', 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-armv7-2.7/ios_mail.o', 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-armv7-2.7/ios_browser.o', '-o', 'build/lib.macosx-10.9-armv7-2.7/ios.so']
Unknown option:  -Qunused-arguments
error: command '/Users/fribu/kivy-ios/tools/liblink' failed with exit status 1
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search indicate it's a flag that clang doesn't know, i don't know kivy-ios much, but this patch https://github.com/JanX2/Etoile/commit/e7b2a3484726d3c3e8b0c0a1cb879021e851a911 should give you a lead at fixing this.